# env.php in Docker containers with pipeline deployment

Tags: magento2, deploy, docker, deployment, magento2.4

## I wanna be able to deploy and run Magento 2 using **Docker images**

I am following Magento 2.2+ pipeline deployment docs:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/deployment/

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-deployment.html

### When runnning pre-build php image with Magento source code, I need to create app/etc/env.php

I have tried to set configuration for **env.php** via `bin/magento setup:config:set` in my **entrpoint** (from ENV vars) which creates env.php file, but it does not include a way how to set `'install' => ['date' => 'Fri, 31 Jun 2020 18:00:00 +0000']` configuration. So Magento still does not know, that system is installed, and redirects to /setup.

Magento installation runs seprately (before runtime containers are created), and runtime containers should be able to scale easily.

And I dont want to rely on Docker volumes to bind app/etc/ folder to runtime containers. Containers should be self sufficient.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, i am facing a similar issue.
Did you find a way to handle it ?

Comment: Hi @MatMouth I did, and it is flawless. Let me know, if my own answer to this topis is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not generating env.php via `bin/magento setup:config:setup`, instead I run `setup:install` in different container before I startup my php-fpm containers.

This setup container at the end copies its (newely generated) app/etc/env.php into shared volume (ex. app/init).

Then, when php-fpm container starts, its entrypoint copies this pre-generated env.php from shared volume to its app/etc/env.php.

This way all the containers are immutabble and deterministic.